# Generic parameter with additional constraint through intersection types

Tags: java, generics

I am writing a class to represent time series data, i.e. basically a map of `(Instant, T)` pairs for a generic type `T`

```
interface TimeSeries<T> {
     void add(Instant when, T data);
}
```

Some of the classes we deal with implement an interface

```
interface TimeStamped {
    Instant getTimeStamp();
}
```

and I want to provide a more convenient method in the `TimeSeries` interface to add such data items without stating the time explicity. Basically, I want

```
interface TimeSeries<T> {
     void add(Instant when, T data);
     default <X extends T & TimeStamped> void add(X data) {
         add(data.getTimeStamp(), data);   
     } 
}
```

[but this seems not allowed by the language because I cannot use type variables in intersection types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46912276/restrictions-on-java-intersection-types-with-interfaces-classes-and-type-variabl). Is there a work-around that does not involve giving up static type-safety? The only things I can come up with are

```
interface TimeSeries<T> {
     void add(Instant when, T data);
     default void add(TimeStamped data) {
         add(data.getTimeStamp(), (T)data);   
     }
     default void add(TimeStamped t, T data) {
         add(t.getTimeStamp(), data);
     } 
}
```

`add(TimeStamped t, T data)` is type-safe but still inconvenient.

Comment: A simple workaround would be a `interface TimeStampedTimeSeries<T extends TimeStamped> extends TimeSeries<T>` - you could use it when populating the timeseries and when consuming it you could just refer to `TimeSeries<?>`.

Comment: Another workaround is to use a static method static <X extends TimeStamped> void add(TimeSeries<? super X> timeSeries, X x)

Comment: @cppbeginner that one however doesn't bring any extra simplicity.

Comment: Why not? OP wants to write timeSeries.add(x). Instead you can write add(timeSeries, x).

Comment: Well, ok, it allows you to only provide the object once, plus you could use static imports. It still breaks the pattern though.

Comment: @assylias I would accept your suggestion as an answer (and also Vlasec's comment, but I can only accept one). Do you want to post an answer?

Comment: I summed up and then, right after posting, I came up with a new idea of my own, but it's not great news either.

Comment: What approach did you choose in the end? Can you tell me in response to my answer? :)

Comment: @Vlasec I created a TimeStamped-only interface. The generic interface is just used to define the data structure in an application-agnostic way, and in the application we can use the TimeStamped-only interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I understand your question. Basically, you could have a `TimeSeries` with some simple type that doesn't implement `TimeStamped`, but some of its subclasses do. In those cases, not even the workaround by @assylias helps.

Well, I think there is no clean solution for this problem in Java 8, and I have no experience with Java 9, but I didn't notice anything like that while reading about its new features. That means you either sacrifice static type safety or comfort.

It is kinda hard to tell what is the best workaround. Basically what we have here so far is:

- TimeStamped-only interface for the cases where your base object already implements the `TimeStamped` interface, as advised by @assylias.
- Static method as advised by @cppbeginner. I don't like the syntax though, it is meant as syntax sugar, but you end up with a static call. It's quite versatile though and does what you want.
- Give up on the syntax sugar idea entirely and just type it like a slave.
- Give up type safety and have a nice code that can backfire.
- Oh wait, one more possibility. Make it a method of `TimeStamped` interface instead, with the `TimeSeries` as an argument. Actually better than going static, but kinda bottom up.

I can't decide which one is better for you as I don't know your use case. None of them is perfect. I already encountered this issue and I found no super-smart solution either. Another thing I was unable to do is a generic enum. I mean, why not, it would be interesting if it was possible (but it's not, either).