# Generic type restriction bound by two other generic types

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to make a method's generic return type be bound by two the generic types of the arguments, in the sense that it should be the lowest common type of the two. For example:

```
class Scratch {

    static <T, U, R /*additional restrictions*/> R getLowestCommon(T t, U u) {
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object o = getLowestCommon("", 1);
        CharSequence s = getLowestCommon("", new StringBuilder());
        Number n = getLowestCommon(1L, 2D);
        Collection<Integer> c = getLowestCommon(new ArrayList<Integer>(), new HashSet<Integer>());
        // this should give an error because ArrayList's and HashSet's lowest common supertype is Collection
        List<Integer> l = getLowestCommon(new ArrayList<Integer>(), new HashSet<Integer>());
    }
}
```

I know  about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46912276/restrictions-on-java-intersection-types-with-interfaces-classes-and-type-variabl) restriction to intersection types, but is there any way I can make this compile-time restriction in Java?

Comment: Lowest common is type always `Object`. I guess you mean highest common?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about declaring `T` and `U` extend from R.

```
static <T extends R, U extends R, R > R getLowestCommon(T t, U u)
```

Comment: As with my answer, the return type in his `Collection` example will actually be `AbstractCollection`, which is presumably desirable.

Comment: @Michael I agree there is no need to have two type parameters here. But even with this, the return type can be `AbstractCollection` right?

Answer (score 2):

You've overcomplicated it. You just need one generic type parameter and Java will infer the rest:

```
static <T> T getLowestCommon(T t, T u) {
    return null;
}
```

In this case, it will actually infer the return type to be `AbstractCollection`, rather than `Collection` as you were expecting, as `ArrayList` and `HashSet` both happen to extend that class. `AbstractCollection` still implements `Collection`, though, so your example still holds true.

Comment: It works and is functionally equivalent to @user7's answer, but I think I like in this case that answer better because it _explicitly_ transmits that `t` and `u` can be of different types. Thanks!